# Why sp_WhoIsActive blocking_session_id IS NULL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Currently in my database server is too much slow. Running,

```
EXEC sp_WhoIsActive
    @find_block_leaders = 1,
    @sort_order = '[blocked_session_count] DESC'
```

Sometimes we get below error,

```
Msg 530, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_WhoIsActive, Line 4316 [Batch Start Line 17]
The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.
```

and when it runs, blocked_session_count to higher number but blocking_session_id is NULL. There is something is blocking and I am unable to find it out.

[image]

Also running,

```
SELECT COUNT(*),log_reuse_wait_desc FROM master.sys.databases group by log_reuse_wait_desc
```

returns | 60 | LOG_BACKUP|

[image]

When I do failover it starts working but I cannot keep doing failover.

Comment: Can you edit your question to add a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Comment: @ErikDarling updated

Comment: Do you get a root `session_id` with the following script: [ADMIN_Blocking_Locking_Hierarchical.sql](https://github.com/JohnKNess/SQL-Server-Scripts/blob/main/ADMIN_Blocking_Locking_Hierarchical.sql) (JohnKNess | Github Repository)?

Comment: Ran your script and it returns https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBEHH.png. Does there is something I can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lead blockers are often not being blocked -- they're causing the blocking because they're running for a long time waiting on something else, or sleeping and waiting for another instruction. During that time they're holding locks. Note that lock waits come from blocking, not [locks being taken](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/query-tuning/lock-waits-come-from-blocking-not-locks-being-taken/).

WhoIsActive only orders (in your scenario) by which sessions have the most blocked sessions under them. They could be entirely unrelated. What you're probably looking for is something that walks the blocking chain to show you the lead blocker, and then all of their blocked sessions.

Some helpful scripts for that are here:

- [dbo.Check_Blocking](https://am2.co/2017/10/finding-leader-blocker/)
- [Identifying Blocking Chain Using sp_WhoIsActive](https://ajaydwivedi.com/2020/08/sql-server-blocking-tree-identifying-blocking-chain-using-sp_whoisactive)
- [Look at Blocked Process Reports Collected With Extended Events](https://michaeljswart.com/2016/02/look-at-blocked-process-reports-collected-with-extended-events/)

Comment: Now dbo.Check_Blocking returning `Msg 9420, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Check_Blocking, Line 339 [Batch Start Line 0]
XML parsing: line 1, character 369, illegal xml character`

Comment: @user960567 I don't maintain that project, you'd have to take it up with the author.

Comment: Hi! I'm the author of that procedure. I've gotten reports of this error in the past, but never enough details to identify the issue. If you can reproduce, or identify a specific value/column that might be causing the error, please [create an issue](https://github.com/amtwo/dba-database/issues) with details.

Comment: @AMtwo glad to see the creator of this awesome tool. Actually, under heavy load it regularly come but normally no. I can see if I can reproduce it.

Comment: You can try using [this alternate version](https://gist.github.com/amtwo/10d3856e75fc9c6989bb3fb1c4277f3f), which skips building the XML for the `SessionInfo` column entirely.  I also had a side chat with @Erik and have a possible fix to try later on when I have a little more time.

Comment: Thanks @AMtwo will try this